# Java Socket error with sending and receiving

Tags: java, network-programming

I've got a really strange problem, if I send a message from server/client to server/client they wont be sended in the console.
I've tried the whole day to fix it and googled it before how to fix it, but I can't find an answer for my problem, that's why I ask it here.

```
My Code:

Serversocket:
package me.jackboyplay.sockets_server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author JackboyPlay
 */
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(1243);
            System.out.println("Gestartet...");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(socket == null){
            System.out.println("NULL -> Aus");
            return;
        }
        while(true){
            try {
                new Clients(socket.accept()).start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

    package me.jackboyplay.sockets_server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author JackboyPlay
 */
public class Clients extends Thread{

    Socket socket;
    DataInputStream dis;
    PrintStream dos;

    public Clients(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dos = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Clients.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread started...");
        String receive = null;
        while(true){
            try {
                receive = dis.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Clients.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if(receive != null){
                System.out.println(receive);
                dos.println("Out");
                dos.flush();
            }
        }
    }

}
Client:

    package me.jackboyplay.sockets_client;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author JackboyPlay
 */
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 1243);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(socket == null){
            return;
        }
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        PrintWriter dos = null;
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dos = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String receive = null;
        while(true){
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                receive = dis.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            if(receive != null){
                dos.println("Hallo");
                dos.flush();
                try {
                    receive = dis.readLine();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println(receive);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you don't get a compiler error? Then is it a run-time error (exception)? Unexpected results? And if you have multiple files that you show in the question, please try to separate them with some non-code text (like their file-name). If you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should probably also read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: The first thing you do on the server is wait reading until the client sends a line of text. The first thing you say on the client is wait reading until the server sends a line of text. You implemented a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Both ends start by receiving from the socket. You are deadlocked. Reconsider your application protocol